# Compile C++ file as objective-c++ using makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, objective-c++

I'm trying to compile .cpp files as objective-c++ using makefile as few of my cpp file have objective code. I added -x objective-c++ as complier option and started getting stray /327 in program error( and lots of similar error with different numbers after /). The errors are around 200. But when I change the encoding of the file from unicode-8 to 16 the error reduces to 23. currently there is no objective-c++ code in the .cpp file but plan to add in future.
When i remove -x objective-c++ from complier option ,everything complies fine. and .out is generated. I would be helpful if someone will tell me why this is happening and even a solution for the same 
Thanks in advance

example of my makefile

```
MACHINE= $(shell uname -s)


CFLAGS?=-w -framework CoreServices -framework ApplicationServices -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreWLAN -framework Cocoa -framework Foundation

ifeq ($(MACHINE),Darwin)
  CCLINK?= -lpthread 
else
 CCLINK?= -lpthread -lrt 
endif   

DEBUG?= -g -rdynamic -ggdb 
CCOPT= $(CFLAGS)  $(ARCH) $(PROF)
CC =g++ -x objective-c++
AR = ar rcs
#lib name
SLIB_NAME=myapplib
EXENAME = myapp.out
OBJDIR = build

OBJLIB := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/... all .o files)


SS_OBJ := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,myapp.o  )

vpath %.cpp path to my .cpp files



INC  = include files


subsystem:

     make all

$(OBJLIB) : |$(OBJDIR)
$(OBJDIR):
     mkdir $(OBJDIR) 


$(OBJDIR)/%.o:%.cpp 
    $(CC) -c  $(INC) $(CCOPT) $(DEBUG) $(CCLINK) $< -o $@


all:  $(OBJLIB) $(CLI_OBJ) $(SS_OBJ)
    $(AR)  lib$(SLIB_NAME).a $(OBJLIB)
    $(CC)  $(INC) $(CCOPT) $(SS_OBJ) $(DEBUG) $(CCLINK) -l$(SLIB_NAME) -L ./ -o $(OBJDIR)/$(EXENAME) 


clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)/*
dep:
    $(CC) -MM *.cpp
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? Can you give a minimal example that would allow anyone to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @DevSolar i'm using g++ i have given a sample makefile

Comment: "Minimal" would still include a short "hello world" type source file, which exhibits the described behaviour. It would also include a Makefile that is devoid of any lines not *directly* contributing to the problem. I'm asking for this because it would a) give you an opportunity to narrow your question further, b) show us that you have taken an effort to do so, c) make it easier for us to actually reproduce the error, and check if our suggestions work *before* posting them.

Comment: Conventionally Objective-C++ files have the extension `.mm`; try changing the relevant file extensions and leaving the pure C++ files as `.cpp`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't want to name files as .mm need to be .cpp as this files will be used in windows

Comment: I need the error code, not just part of it. I need minimal files that cause the problem.

Comment: The slashes in your question are the wrong way around. Look closely an the error.

Comment: @richard I'm sorry i forgot to mention one thing in the question,I'm trying to build VS2008 project. I did created a small Helloworld project on mac and compiled it using g++ -x objective-c++.It worked fine. I had faced similar problem when compiling same vs project using g++ for one of the file. I changed file ending to mac os x/unix (LR) and it compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a stray × (multiply sign) outside of a quoted string. All C/C++ must be ASCII, except what is in a string.

Note: ASCII converted to UTF-8 is ASCII. If utf-16 then not quoted strings must be ASCII equivalent, supposing compiler supports utf-16. Also the to file formats may produce different code, differing in the strings produced.